# iPhone: How to fix a legacy iPhone app which has really bad memory management? unittesting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, unit-testing

I recently inherited an iPhone app. The original developer did not understand memory management and well the app works in simlulator but not in on old iPhone (lots of crashses).  Do you have any thoughts on the process by which I can save the app?

Can I utilize or create any unittest to find memory leaks and make the process 'scientific'?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Use Clang! Here is a good tutorial showing the benefits: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/clang-static-analyzer.html

However, it should be installed if you have a newer SDK.

Comment: On the same topic, there's also: http://www.oiledmachine.com/posts/2009/01/06/using-the-llvm-clang-static-analyzer-for-iphone-apps.html

Comment: Yes, the link I posted is actually quite old. If you're using a newer SDK, you shouldn't need to download, just select llvm as your compiler, and make sure you run the analyzer.

Comment: You don't need to select Clang LLVM as the compiler. The analyzer works fine regardless of which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Clang Static Analyzer is now built-in to Xcode on Snow Leopard, it's trivial to use it. Select `Build -> Build & Analyze` to see any memory problems Clang detects (hint: it will find pretty much all of them).

Comment: Better yet, turn on the “Run Static Analyzer” build setting. Then Xcode will run the analyzer on every build.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: The only problem with that is as of Xcode 3.2.1, having this setting enabled can cause problems with codesense :(

Comment: jbrennan: Huh? That makes no sense. Could you be more specific, or link to something that is?